# jQuery Slider, finding value of the selected' when bound to select

Tags: jquery, select, slider, selected, jsfiddle

I've got a tiny issue that I am trying to work out.

I've put the problem into JSFiddle with their been quite a lot of options in the select html http://jsfiddle.net/dANW8/

here is the JS for the actual slider but it's easier to check the jsfiddle

```
    $(function () {
        var select = $('#hdd');
        var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 45,
            range: "true",
            value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
                $("#hddValue").text(ui.value);
            }
        });
    //show start value
    $( "#hddValue" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
    });
```

I basically want to output the actual value of the selected item, so instead of outputting the actual index number that goes from 1-45 I want to show that value of it instead.

Anyone got any idea how I can do this?

Thanks in advance for time spent looking,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the text of `selected` option of the select.

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dANW8/2/)**

Change

```
 $("#hddValue").text(ui.value);
```

To

```
  $("#hddValue").text($('#hdd option:selected').text());
```

Comment: There seems to be an off-by-one error where scrolling hard left: It gives an index of -1.  To fix:   select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value;   http://jsfiddle.net/dANW8/3/

Comment: Thanks Adil, works spot on, @SteveWellens doing that means that a hard right would also give an off by one error, if I set the minimum to 1 instead of 0 on the range then it seems to be okay! thanks for noticing this

Answer (score 0):

You need to make just simple math couting:
Update this:

```
$("#hddValue").text(ui.value*10+40);
```

You also missing one option in your select:

```
  <option>400 GB - step 36</option>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the missing step! The previously posted method by Adil seems a bit easier than a math alternative though, which way would you choose?